# Facebook/Google+/Twitter sharing ability inside iOS web app

Tags: html, ios, iframe, mobile-safari, iphone-web-app

I'm creating a web app for iOS, and user must pin website to homescreen to launch the app.

My web app is a news reader, and I want to add social sharing of articles in my app.

In a web app, if a web app tries to open a new tab or a popup window, Mobile Safari launches, and after closing mobile safari, user will come back to home screen, and **not to my app.**

So I can't use their sharing buttons, since they open popup windows for logging in and sharing...

Also, they are blocking `iframe` tags, so I can't load login and sharing pages inside an `iframe` on my web app.

So, What's the best way to integrate sharing possibility (Facebook/Twitter/Google+) in my web app? (Sharing inside my web app, or come back from mobile safari to my app, or ...)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've found a way to solve this problem, **just for facebook**. *(If someone knows how to solve this problem with Google+ and Twitter, please let me know. Thanks)*

It is possible by using [**Facebook Dialogs**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/).

The easiest way to implement sharing is using [**Feed Dialog**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). It shows a login page, and then shows a sharing page, and then comes back to the url you specify in the query string. But there is just one problem: User can't back to the application from facebook login page (but he can cancel sharing from sharing page, the page shows after login page)

Another way, which is better but a little harder to implement, is using [**Login (OAuth) Dialog**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/), and then implement sharing by a [**like and/or send plugin**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/). You should first check if user has logged in (in facebook) with facebook javascript SDK, then if user has logged in, show like/send buttons, and if user is not logged in, redirect to Login Dialog for logging in, and then show like and send buttons.

The advantage of the second method is, after user logs in into facebook, then he can share and like whatever you like in a nice AJAX way, and without any redirects. I think it's faster, and of course it is cool!

Comment: Good job mate, i've think that facebook might be the hardest one.